# How does composition work in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, composition

I'm trying to use composition in hibernate with annotations.

I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo")
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    public void setBar(Bar bar){...}
    public Bar getBar() {...)
}

public class Bar {
  private double x;

  public void setX(double x) {...}
  public double getX() {...}
}
```

And when trying to save Foo, I'm getting

> Could not determine type for entity
>   org.bla.Bar at table Foo for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(bar)]

I tried putting an @Entity annotation on Bar, but this gets me:

> No identifier specified for entity
>   org.bla.Bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mechanism is described in this section of the reference docs:

### [5.1.5. Embedded objects (aka components)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component)

Apparently hibernate uses JPA annotations for this purpose, so the solution [referred to by Ralph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284836/how-does-composition-work-in-hibernate/4284874#4284874) is correct

In a nutshell:

if you mark a class `Address` as `@Embeddable` and add a property of type `Address` to class `User`, marking the property as `@Embedded`, then the resulting database table `User` will have all fields specified by `Address`.

See Ralph's answer for the code.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specifiy the relationship between `Foo` and `Bar` (with something like @ManyToOne or @OneToOne).

Alternatively, if `Bar` is not an Entity, then mark it with @Embeddable, and add @Embedded to the variable declaration in `Foo`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo")
public class Foo {
    @Embedded
    private Bar bar;

    public void setBar(Bar bar){...}
    public Bar getBar() {...)
}

@Embeddable
public class Bar {
  private double x;

  public void setX(double x) {...}
  public double getX() {...}
}
```

See: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable  -- The example expains the @Embeddable and @Embedded Composite way, where `Foo` and `Bar` (`Company` and `ContactPerson` in the example) are mapped in the same Table.

Comment: I'm reading through the link you sent - I believe that it assumes I would like to normalize the table representation. However, I think that in my case I prefer to embed these columns in one master table. Meaning - I want one table with all of Foo & Bar's fields as columns. Assuming this is indeed what I want - how can I achieve that with Hibernate?

Comment: @Ripper234: No, have a look at the table in the example, it contains Stundent and Address fields. (The ER-Diagramme is a bit confusing, because it shows the more logical view, and not the Database.)

Comment: `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` are not hibernate annotations, they are only available in JPA. The tutorial you linked to is pretty awful (not only because it doesn't mention that it's using JPA)

Comment: Thanks, I was simply missing an @Embedded annotation. Please edit your answer to include this.

Comment: To qualify my above statement: they are JPA annotations, but they are apparently the standard hibernate way to do it (see my answer)

Comment: @Floyed: But hibernate implements JPA, so where is the point?

Comment: @ralph a) it's floyd, not floyed and it's my last name, use Sean. b) hibernate entitymanager implements jpa, hibernate core doesn't. c) in my own answer I describe the exact code you write. Still you downvote me?

Comment: @Sean: Sorry for the wrong name. But @Embedded and @Embeddable are  reference by Hibernate-Annotations. It is the standart Hibernate way it has noting to do with hibernate entitymanager. It will work without Entity Manager (I use this way in one of my old applications).

Comment: They are referenced, yes. But they belong to JPA (package name is javax.persistence). And previous versions of hibernate core didn't use JPA at all. Read these maven POMs for reference: JPA in 3.6: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.0.Final/hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.pom , no JPA in 3.5: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.0-Final/hibernate-core-3.5.0-Final.pom

Comment: You are correct: hibernate core was never aware of annotations at all. But Hibernate-Annotation works with javax.persictence

Comment: Changed my answer, Foo and Bar are bad example classes.

Comment: To clear up the misunderstanding: I wasn't referring to the OP's Foo and Bar classes. I only now realized that he also named his classes Foo and Bar. And in my Foo and Bar classes the relationship was opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Each **simple** entity must be marked as an entity (with `@Entity`) and have an identifier (mostly a Long) as a primary key. Each non-primitive association/composition must be declared with the corresponding association annotation (`@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`). I suggest you read through the [Hibernate Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/). Try the following to make your code example work

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Bar bar;

    // getters and setters for id and bar
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private double x;

    // getters and setters for id and x
}
```

Comment: This creates two separate tables, but the OP wants bar's fields in foo's table.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd Not necessarily. 'Composition' refers to the Java code, and OOP in general, and not the database mapping. OOP composition can be mapped and stored in multiple ways, including `@OneToOne` (using foreign key), `@OneToOne` (using shared primary key), `@Embedded`, etc.