# Reusing fields for JPA entities in native query

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, nativequery

We use JPA in our project but there are certain complex queries that need to be done straightforward in native query. We make use JPA native queries for this, like the one below

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString(), "SomeEntityQuery");
```

then we created an entity called SomeEntity which has a code like the one below

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="SomeEntityQuery",
        entities={
            @EntityResult(
                entityClass=SomeEntity.class,
                fields={
                    @FieldResult(name="fieldOne", column="FieldOne"),
                    @FieldResult(name="fieldTwo", column="FieldTwo"),
                    @FieldResult(name="fieldThree", column="FieldThree")
                }
            )
        }
    )


@Entity
public class SomeEntity{

//fields listed below
```

My question is, what if we have a dao method that has the following methods that we translated to native queries

`methodA()` which returns SomeEntityObject but only fills up `fieldOne`, `fieldTwo`, `fieldThree`

`methodB()` which returns `SomeEntityObject` but only fills up `fieldFour`, `fieldFive`, `fieldSix`

we noticed that when creating `@SqlResultSetMapping`, all fields need to be defined or else an exception would be thrown if not.

What if the dao methods (which has native queries) stretches up to `methodE()` and we don't want to have a different Entity return for every dao method? we would want to use the same SomeEntity object for all.

Is there a workaround for my dilemma?

The sql for that is...

```
  SELECT a.someColumn as FieldOne , b.someColumn as FieldTwo , c.someColumn as FieldThree...etc..etc..
```

Comment: Have you considered breaking up your entity into parts that map to your mapping methods and then using composition to containerize them for your application?

Comment: How do you break an entity into parts?

Comment: Check out this SO question, the answer gives a good synopsis:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284836/how-does-composition-work-in-hibernate